# jTextField.setText ERROR. Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, swing

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        String pwd = jTextField2.getText();
        String EncryptionKey = "dhsakjh7324afe24";
        AESExample aes = new AESExample(EncryptionKey);
        String enc = aes.encrypt(pwd);
        String res = jTextField3.setText("Encryption complete." + enc);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Crypto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

How can I handle this.. I have to put the encrypted password got on a button action in the textfield that is not editable

Comment: `setText()` is a `void` method it does not return a `String`. so your line `String res = jTextField3.setText("Encryption complete." + enc);` will not work...

Comment: most likely your program did not compile, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 jTextField3.setText("Encryption complete." + enc);
```

You can simply do this in the last line of your code. .

Answer (score 1):

You change the last two lines so that:

```
    String res = jTextField3.setText("Encryption complete." + aes.encrypt(pwd));
```

You are not using the variable `enc` more than once.

Answer (score 1):

String res only can getText, not to setText.

So try.

```
jTextField3.setText("Encryption complete." + enc);
String res= jTextField3.getText();
```